# RxJava2 how to observe UDP packets?

Tags: android, multithreading, udp, rx-java2

I am just getting started with RxJava2 and wonder how I could correctly implement a UDP observable.
I already have some working code, but I think there may be some issues: see the 4 questions in the comments of the source-code below.

I've also published the code on GitHub [RxJava2_Udp](https://github.com/tmtron/RxJava2_Udp/tree/329bbf1f6fb41b83bc16aec1431ddd01e538e6ff): comments, issues and pull requests welcome.

```
class UdpObservable {

    private static class UdpThread extends Thread {
        private final int portNo;
        private final int bufferSizeInBytes;
        private final ObservableEmitter<DatagramPacket> emitter;
        private DatagramSocket udpSocket;

        private UdpThread(@NonNull ObservableEmitter<DatagramPacket> emitter
                , int portNo, int bufferSizeInBytes) {
            this.emitter = emitter;
            this.portNo = portNo;
            this.bufferSizeInBytes = bufferSizeInBytes;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // we don't want to create the DatagramSocket in the constructor, because this
                // might raise an Exception that the observer wants to handle
                udpSocket = new DatagramSocket(portNo);
                try {
                    /* QUESTION 1:
                       Do I really need to check isInterrupted() and emitter.isDisposed()?

                       When the thread is interrupted an interrupted exception will
                       be raised anyway and the emitter is being disposed (this is what
                       caused the interruption)
                    */
                    while (!isInterrupted() && !emitter.isDisposed()) {
                        byte[] rcvBuffer = new byte[bufferSizeInBytes];
                        DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(rcvBuffer, rcvBuffer.length);
                        udpSocket.receive(datagramPacket);
                        // QUESTION 1a: same as QUESTION 1 above
                        if (!isInterrupted() && !emitter.isDisposed()) {
                            emitter.onNext(datagramPacket);
                        }
                    }
                } finally {
                    closeUdpSocket();
                }
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                // the thread will only be interrupted when the observer has unsubscribed:
                // so we need not report it
                if (!isInterrupted()) {
                    if (!emitter.isDisposed()) {
                        emitter.onError(th);
                    } else {
                        // QUESTION 2: is this the correct way to handle errors, when the emitter
                        //             is already disposed?
                        RxJavaPlugins.onError(th);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void closeUdpSocket() {
            if (!udpSocket.isClosed()) {
                udpSocket.close();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void interrupt() {
            super.interrupt();
            // QUESTION 3: this is called from an external thread, right, so
            //             how can we correctly synchronize the access to udpSocket?
            closeUdpSocket();
        }
    }

    /**
     * creates an Observable that will emit all UDP datagrams of a UDP port.
     * <p>
     * This will be an infinite stream that ends when the observer unsubscribes, or when an error
     * occurs. The observer does not handle backpressure.
     * </p>
     */
    public static Observable<DatagramPacket> create(final int portNo, final int bufferSizeInBytes) {
        return Observable.create(
                new ObservableOnSubscribe<DatagramPacket>() {
                    @Override
                    public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<DatagramPacket> emitter) throws Exception {
                        final UdpThread udpThread = new UdpThread(emitter, portNo, bufferSizeInBytes);
                        /* QUESTION 4: Is this the right way to handle unsubscription?
                         */
                        emitter.setCancellable(new Cancellable() {
                            @Override
                            public void cancel() throws Exception {
                                udpThread.interrupt();
                            }
                        });
                        udpThread.start();
                    }
                }
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: The "4 questions in the comments" are missing. Update the question with them.

Comment: they are in the source-code comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Generally speaking, I think it is not the right way of creating it, you should not create thread yourself, as RxJava and it's `Schedulers` should do it for you.
  Consider that the code that code executed at the `ObservableOnSubscribe` will run at a thread per your `Scheduler` strategy, so you don't need to construct it yourself. just do the ude while-loop inside the create.
- You don't need to call `Thread.interrupt()` method, RxJava will do that for you when you're dispose (unsubscribe) the `Observable`. (set the `cancelable` before the while loop of course)

As for your questions:

1. You don't need to check for the interrupted as the exception will
   be raise if you'r waiting for io operation, you also don't need to
   check for the disposal because `onNext()` will do it for you and will
   not emit of unsubscribed.
2. Again you can call `onError` and the emitter will take care of checking if the `Observable`  was unsubscribed.
3. As said before, there should be no Thread, but for resource cleanup, you can use the `emitter.setCancellable` method. (close the stream), this is happen on the same thread your code runs.
4. Answered before, Thread.interrput() will be raised with dispose/unsubscribe by RxJava, resource clean up should go to the `emitter.setCancellable` method

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer. This helped me learn a lot and the code in [UdpObservable](https://github.com/tmtron/RxJava2_Udp/blob/40a63475044b93f6f7ecb0c7d7c5aee98a651391/app/src/main/java/com/tmtron/rxjava2udp/UdpObservable.java)  is now more concise and much clearer.

Comment: Thank you for providing this, @TmTron. Very helpful!